# Getting null when retrieving data through Partition and Row Key

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

```
public T GetSingle<T>(string PartitionKey, string RowKey) where T : TableEntity
{
    // Create a retrieve operation that takes a customer entity.
    TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(PartitionKey, RowKey);

    // Execute the retrieve operation.
    TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);  
}
```

My retrievedResult is always null. I have the table reference. Please help me to find my issue.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, the values for `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` are case-sensitive. Please make sure the values for `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` are exactly match with your stored entity. Moreover, you could leverage [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network traces when you executing the table query to narrow down this issue. For the common tutorials, you could follow [Get started with Azure Table storage and the Azure Cosmos DB Table API using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json).